# Match links to video-sharing sites

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to scan text for links to some video-sharing sites so I can create an embedded player when videos are linked to.

This is what I've got so far:

```
function extract(&$text) {
    // Scans text for links to YouTube, Vimeo, DailyMotion.

    // *keep ~discard
    // youtube.com/watch?v=[*alphanumeric]&[~whatever]
    // youtube-nocookie.com/watch?v=[*alphanumeric]&[~whatever]
    // vimeo.com/[*numeric]
    // dailymotion.com/video/[*alphanumeric]_[~whatever]

    $sites = 'youtube\.com|youtube-nocookie\.com|vimeo\.com|dailymotion\.com';
    $regex = '/^(http|https):\/\/(www\.|)(' . $sites . ')\/.*/';
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $videos);
    return $videos;
}
```

This is working oddly. It found no results on the following text:

```
And what about YouTube videos?

http://www.youtube.com/timminchin#p/a/u/2/zkGEbRrNNtE

http://www.youtube.com/timminchin#p/a/f/1/zU4iyjoVWQ

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzU4iyjoVWQ

http://www.youtube-nocookie.com
```

It found one result on this text:

```
http://youtube.com/watch?v=XzU4iyjoVWQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzU4iyjoVWQ
```

And works fine on texts which contain just a single link and nothing else.

I'm not nearly as au fait with regular expressions as I should be, and used http://www.strfriend.com to help me to construct this one.

All I want is an array of URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regular expression to the following:

```
/(http|https):\/\/(www\.|)(' . $sites . ')\/[^\s]*/
```

Differences:

The `^` in the beginning makes the regular expression look only at the beginning of the text, instead of everywhere.

The `[\s]` in the beginning makes sure you can find two links in one line of text.

The last URL won't be found because there is no trailing slash in the end of the URL. If you're trying to detect videos, this won't matter, though, because the video is always on a subpage.

Comment: Tested. Works perfectly. Now embedded videos are appended to the ends of posts in the forum. Lovely.